# "No wifi adapter found"

Tags: wireless

On my newly installed Ubuntu the Wifi cannot be opened and  in the Wifi setting it always shows "no Wifi adapter found". What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "Software Updater" to see if there are any updates for your wifi adapter. It happened to me once and just updating did the trick.