# MSI GS 65 Ubuntu 18 wireless: no wifi adapter found

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, network-manager, intel

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on an MSI GS 65. The wireless doesn't work: it says `no wifi adapter found`. `lshw -C network` says a network is *UNCLAIMED*.

```
hello:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ad414000-ad417fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3d:00.0
       logical name: enp61s0
       version: 10
       serial: 30:9c:23:92:80:3e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=10.10.10.67 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:ad200000-ad23ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

The problem is similar to [this SO question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1016903/alienware-17-r4-ubuntu-16-04-wifi-driver) but I have a different kernel version: `4.15.0-43-generic`.

Contrary to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003398/no-wifi-adapter-found) I think the wireless used to work but has stopped working since I installed some Ubuntu suggested updates. But I am not too sure.

Answer (score 1):

I checked my device using `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`. This gave me the PCI id (8086:a370). I searched with that and found [this forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-killer-wireless-ac-1550i-adapter-9560ngw-not-work/46167/2). It clearly says that it is supported for kernel >= 4.16. Ubuntu 18.04 has 4.15.

You can just upgrade the kernel to solve the problem. Since I have nvidia drivers installed I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10 which has 4.18. This indeed solved the problem.